# "Marissa did not realize that she _______ at work until she _____ home."

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, exam-questions

> Marissa did not realize that she _______  at work until she _____ home.

*a) forgot the keys / was getting*

*b) had forgotten the keys / got*

*c) has forgotten the keys / gets*

*d) forgot the keys / got*

The authors of this question provided an Answer Keys with only one possible correct choice.

Since I have quite a lot of experience with *time interval in the different parts of grammar*, I honestly see this as a multiple-choice question with multiple correct answers, and little difference in meaning between them.

While all the options *except for c)* are grammatically correct, we simply cannot choose only one option.

Which option would you choose? and WHY?

**Taken from An English Test**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## B

Why? Notice the earlier word *did*. The sentence is constructed in the past tense. Since the **most recent** event in the sentence was Marissa getting home, and we are writing in the past tense, we use *got*.

Since we know that she forgot her keys **before** arriving at her home, we need to make that clear by using the perfect past. Now we have our answer.

> Marissa did not realize that she **had forgotten the keys** at work until she **got** home.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You want to say that the order of events is not clear and unnatural, so we must use the past perfect tense. Right?

Comment: @AlexRaw The act of forgetting should be past perfect because it is clear that Marissa forgets her keys **before** she realizes that she forgot them, and both events are completed actions. This is why (a), (c), and (d) are incorrect. As Micah points out, the order of events is important.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "There is no **single** correct answer that can be supported by an English grammar rule."

I think the answer given by Micah Windsor and the comments that follow fail to address the central problem, and the one that Alex Raw seems to be concerned about, though he might have made it more explicit: what grammatical rule will allow you to choose the one 'correct' answer when there are 3 answers that are grammatically correct.

I'm also a native speaker, and none of the answers except c) are unclear or unnatural to me, and none are ungrammatical. I've helped other ELL/ESLs try to understand poorly constructed questions. It's a significant issue because the test score is meaningful for their advancement and placement but the answer is ambiguous.

In this case, every answer except c) is grammatically correct, and nobody has offered any grammatical rule to eliminate or choose any of them. Most people here are probably not linguistic scholars, but objective answers require a supporting authority beyond what the writer may consider logical and reasonable if we are to truly aid English Language Learners.

English is neither logical nor reasonable, and calling the poster's motives into question is not an appropriate response. The guidelines we operate under here *always* require respect for the original author.

Comment: You dismissed (c) as being grammatically incorrect without an explanation, and then proceeded to say that no one has offered any grammatical rule to eliminate any of the answers. Why is (c) grammatically incorrect? You may find that the logic with which you eliminate (c) as an answer is also the logic with which you can eliminate several other answers.

Comment: @ Micah Windsor - I'm sorry you've taken this stance Micah - now you're being intentionally rude to me. I don't claim to be a scholar, and if you interpret my style of communicating as overly pedantic I can only say I'm regret that it offends you. Certainly it wasn't my intention - it's the way I've always written. But I am trying to be a pedant, in the sense of teaching. And I absolutely believe that questioning the motives of a non-native speaker when they disagree with or misunderstand your answer is not showing respect for their efforts to learn. I'll answer your question elsewhere.

Comment: @Kman3 - and Micah as well - I thought we agreed c) was wrong because it is a direct contradiction in tense: 'Did' is past tense while 'has forgotten' is the present perfect. 'Get' is simple present. 

But the same is not true of the other examples. a) 'did not realize = past [in all examples]; 'forgot = past; 'was getting' = past progressive. b) 'had forgotten' = past perfect; 'got' = past. d) 'forgot' = past; 'got' = past. No tense contradictions.

Comment: @Kman3 and Micah continued.

And no time interval contradictions. 

a) She realized (past) that something happened in the past (she forgot) when something else happened in the past (was getting home).

b)  She realized (past) that something _had_ happened in the past (she forgot) when something else happened in the past (got home).

d) She realized (past) that something happened in the past (she forgot) when something else happened in the past (got home).

Comment: @Kman3 and Micah 

c) *Time interval contradiction:* She realized (past) that something happened in the present (she has forgotten) - *CHRONOLOGICAL IMPOSSIBILITY* - when something happens in the present (gets home) - *CHRONOLOGICAL IMPOSSIBILITY*.

Comment: @MicahWindsor - I'm sorry but I don't understand your question:

_"And I suppose that it is no problem for Marissa to realize she has forgotten her keys before she has forgotten her keys?"_

Which example/s has/have her forgetting the keys before she forgets the keys?

Comment: Allow me to expand upon what @MicahWindsor is saying. For both (a) and (d), the action of _realizing_ and the action in its object clause _forgetting_ are both in the **same (perfect) tense**. This means that both actions happen in the same frame of time, which is impossible. One must _forget_ something **before** they realize that they forgot it. This is why the past perfect (_had forgotten_) must be used: to indicate that the forgetting happened, then it was completed, then the realizing happened. This is why (b) is the correct answer.

Comment: We should continue this in chat. Unfortunately, I'm not able to move the conversation.

Comment: @MicahWindsor - Please don't blame me for your rudeness. Misinterpreting my answer as condescending is no excuse for insults. I expressed regret you felt offended but I think you're overly sensitive. Using words like 'condescending spiel' and 'ramblings' are attempts to further insult me. Nobody has impugned you. I didn't, and I don't think Alex Raw (is that who "OP" is?) was intentionally rude. Maybe his English usage led you to believe he was. You'd have to ask his intentions; you should assume good or neutral intentions unless proven otherwise and not respond with sarcasm and insults.

Comment: I'd be glad to move both conversations to chat; it would be more profitable and I hope less rancorous. I've responded to Micah and I disagree with your latest expansion, but let's drop this here. The chat will have to be at a later time however; I'm sorry but I have to leave my computer for now.

Comment: A few things: (1) Let us all keep this civil. Calling people "pathetic" is impolite and unnecessary. (2) You and Fremonttheboybug both aren't responding to the position @MicahWindsor and I have both outlined several times; you instead seem to be ignoring it in favour of criticizing Micah's tone. In what way is our position incorrect? This is the key to the question. And finally, (3) **Please move this to chat. All it takes is a click of a button.** I look forward to more discussion.

Comment: @MicahWindor *I am going to affirm and accept your answer* if that satisfies you, and 'llow it. I find this discussion unnecessary and needless.